# How to Manually Run ALL Gmail Filters on Entire Inbox?

Tags: gmail

I know you can force a gmail filter to run (by "editing" it but not making any changes, then checking the "also apply to..." box).

But is there a way to select ALL filters and make them run on the entire inbox?

I've got about 50 filters (for my work email I forward to gmail).  Sometimes, it seems like they were sleeping while lots of mail landed in the inbox.  To manually run them one by one is very tedious.

If anyone knows a way to automate the process, I'd love to hear about it!  TIA.

Answer (score 33):

I found another way and it's working like a charm for me, this is about how to recall gmail filters or how to reprocess filters on gmail.

1. settings, filters
2. click edit for the filter you want to recall or process manually
3. skip the first screen click continue
4. on this second windows you may change your settings or just check "Also apply filter to matching conversations." checkbox and click update filter.

There you go everything in your inbox recalled or refiltered manually.

Comment: Great! I've seen the checkbox, but its name is so confusing that I couldn't imagine it does what I want. They must've called it '... to matching e-mails' instead of '... to matching conversations'.

Comment: Same issue here.  It's fantastic once you RTFM but good luck finding it.

Comment: Thanks, Google really need to make this special one-time `checkbox` kind of separate out from others.

Comment: -1. This is already mentioned (admittedly in less detail, but still acknowledged) in the question and does not address the mass management capabilities that the OP requires.

Comment: I see option to apply only to 30 email, but I have hundreds of them

Comment: that not answer the question at all !

Comment: -1 This answer is for a single filter, if you have many filters you would need to do this for every single filter, the question specifically has ALL filters in the title.

Answer (score 28):

This is a bit dated but I came across it during a Google search so I thought some others might land on it.

I found no way to manually run or automatically run all filters.  What I did find though is that you could take a bit of a leap of faith with the following

1. Go into Settings >> Filters
2. Export all your filters to a file you save on your computer
3. Delete all your filters from GMail
4. Import your filters from the saved file
5. When you import you will be able to check a box that will run all the imported filters against existing messages

Comment: that bit of somthing